# Get rid of unwanted input languages in Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, input-languages

When switching between the input languages I have more options (languages) than I set up.
I don't need them and I cannot find any way to get rid of them.

Here's my keyboard layout selector in the taskbar:
[Taskbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J96KM.png)

And here's my input language settings:
[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KGFW.png)

I don't need English (United Kingdom) and russian, and I have no idea where they came from.
Also, the russian language isn't always shown there, sometimes I have to switch past it, sometimes not.

I've been googling it, but haven't found anything relevant so far.

Comment: Honestly, not fully. I did exactly what they suggested and it helped only with the russian language. Which isn't always shown anyway, so I have a feeling it will return in the future. English (United Kingdom) remained as it was even though I installed and uninstalled the entire language pack as suggested.

Comment: So after you installed the language packs and/or keyboard layouts, then removed them, you still have your problem.  Your question mentions none of that.  Here is the thing, ins nearly 100%of the cases of questions with this exact problem, the existing question for Windows 10 and Windows 11 in nearly all cases sovle the problem for other users.